# how to draw 3D object on opencv camera ( rajawali )

Tags: opencv, opengl-es, rajawali

I am doing a project in which I need to render a 3D object on opencv camera in android. I am using OpenGL ES rajawali for rendering. Using my code given below, it first displays the 3D object and then opens camera. Sometimes it displays 3D object and opens the camera simultaneously. I don't know why is it happening. I want to display 3D object on opencv camera. Could you please help me in this?

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    openCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) new JavaCameraView(this, -1);
  // openCvCameraView.setVisibility(mSurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    openCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    mSurfaceView.setVisibility(openCvCameraView.VISIBLE);
    mLayout.addView(openCvCameraView);

    mSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    setGLBackgroundTransparent(true);
    mRenderer = new Renderer(this);
    mRenderer.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView);
    super.setRenderer(mRenderer);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar in my project as shown in the following clip:

[AR Motion Detection on Android with OpenCV and OpenGL (Rajawali)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEioXZT-lv0/)

I've posted the entire project code up for this app so have a look and see if that helps.

You will find the code here:
https://github.com/timegalore/MotionDetectionAR

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want a transparent overlay on top of the OCV camera, right?

At the onCreate, create your camera and surface views then set these parameters (assuming EGL 2.0) on your surface view:

> ```
>         setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
>         getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
>         setZOrderOnTop(true);
> ```

Then you set your renderer for  that surface with:

> ```
>         setRenderer(mRenderer);
> ```

This should be enought for you to have a transparent overlay on top of the OCV surface.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Rajawali´s custom activity assumes that your are not using a xml file for layout. I Strongly recommend you to extend Activity instead of RajawaliActivity

Answer (score 0):

@timegalore I tried to execute your Project but found an error
"block10_obj is missing"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWzMU.png

Answer (score 0):

As of snapshot Rajawali-1.0.186 there is no *RajawaliActivity* and so one can't use `setGLBackgroundTransparent(true)`
 But now you can make the surface transparent simply by setting

> `mSurfaceView.setTransparent(true)`

Where `mSurfaceView` is of type `RajawaliSurfaceView`